# Efficient method for finding points near other points

Tags: data-structures, geospatial

I've got a geospatial search problem that I'm hoping someone can help with.

I have a set of points of class A and B and I'd like to find all points of A within some distance to B.

For example, given the below:

```
----------
| B    B |
|123 4 5 |
----------
```

If points of type A are the numbers in the above and the distance function was to only allow adjacent points, then the result of my search would be all the numbers except '4'.

Using R-Trees, quad trees, and similar concepts allows me to find the closest points to another point, but to find the closest points to other *points* would seem to always require an O(... n) where n is the size of the set of Bs in the example above.

If there are any examples of existing implementations of this type of functionality (none of the major geo-supporting data stores or indexes seem to support it as far as I can tell), or ideas of strategies that might help this work at scale, that would be great to hear about also.

Hoping someone that has some experience in the domain could help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want find closest other points you can use the hierarchy of a quadtree,I.e when you have your query give the other points.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand how using the hierarchy of the Quadtree works for finding closest points to a point, but I can't see how I could use this to solve my problem more efficiently than 'what As are near B1, what As are near B2, etc.' What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a magically efficient way to ask for all As within some distance of any B.